# Why can't I select more than one vertex to set a weight to?

Tags: rigging, vertex-weights

I'm still trying to get situated with Blender as far as trying to find a comfortable model rigging routine like I had with 3DS Max. I feel like I'll never get used to weight painting. I've tried a bit of it and was somewhat struggling.

I know about vertex weighting in edit mode, I just need to know more things that I could probably do like, how to set Autokeys so I can move the bone with the animation slider back and forth to see how fluid the vertices move, I'm also trying to figure out why I can't select more than one vertex to set weights to. The weight table disappears when I do so.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your immediate question,

You select the first vertex with right click.  The easiest to understand way to *add* vertices to the selection is by holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key will right clicking on additional vertices.

Blender has a range of selection tools to aid in mass selection and I recommend you investigate [*box select*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/selecting.html#tool-select-box) (shortcut <kbd>B</kbd>) and [*circle select*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/selecting.html#tool-select-circle) (shortcut <kbd>C</kbd>) reasonably soon.  When you're more comfortable with modeling, the investigate the selection menu.

You can read more about the tools in the manual [Selecting Section](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/selecting.html)

EDIT: In response to a comment that the question is not about selecting more than one vertex, but about how to set weight when more than one vertex is selected:

- Go to the Properties Editor
- Select the Object Data Properties Tab
- Open the Vertex Groups panel if it's not already
- Scroll down and find the Vertex Group you want to add the vertices to.
- Make sure the Weight value is what you want it to be.
- Click *Assign*

[image: Vertex groups read to assign weight of 1]

Comment: I'm well aware of the selection tools and how to select multiple vertices. That's not the problem I'm having. I just need to know why the vertex weight table disappears when selecting multiple vertices. I don't think I want to do "weight painting". I want to manually select vertices and add weights to them.

Comment: You definitely need to rewrite your question, then; because what you wrote in this comment is not at all obvious from the way the question is worded.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I had the same issue, I'm used to maya component editor to assign same value at the same time on multiple vertex.

Blender do not offer this kind of editor instead when you select a vertex in viewport "item" you can see "Vertex Weights" there you can weight using existing vertex group.
Assign the value you want.
After that just select all the vertex you want to have the same value and last selection select the vertex with the correct value.
Then in the same tab "Vertex weight" at the bottom click "copy"

All the selected vertex will now have the value of the one you configured earlier.

Kind of weird ux but at least working :)